# Jquery calls php on nginx, doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, amazon-web-services, nginx

I'm having this issue with my nginx webserver on Amazon AWS.

First of all, this code is working and tested on another server but I need to migrate to my own server and here is where I get the problem.
I have an html page with the following jquery+php code that it's not being executed or something like that:

```
<div class="widget widget-twitter-feed clearfix">
<h4>Twitter Feed</h4>
    <ul id="sidebar-twitter-list-1" class="iconlist">
        <li></li>
    </ul>

    <a href="https://twitter.com/coinnova_ok" class="btn btn-default btn-sm fright">Follow Us on Twitter</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( function($){
        $.getJSON('include/twitter/tweets.php?username=coinnova_ok', function(tweets){
        $("#sidebar-twitter-list-1").html(sm_format_twitter(tweets));
        });
        });
    </script>
```

This is my virtual host configuration on nginx:

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name localhost;

  location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ~ \.html$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.htm;
        include        fastcgi.conf;
  }

  location ~ \.js$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

I also change these settings on my /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .html .js
```

I hope somebody can help me :)

## More Info

This is the tweets.php script that needs to be executed. I add it just fyi, but it works on another server as well:

```
<?php
session_start();

if( isset( $_GET['username'] ) AND $_GET['username'] != '' ):

    require_once('oauth/twitteroauth.php'); //Path to twitteroauth library

    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $limit = ( isset( $_GET['count'] ) AND $_GET['count'] != '' ) ? $_GET['count'] : 2;
    $consumerkey = "LAxZjcBtFOw1wYhJ2Tqm8w";
    $consumersecret = "0SyeOk44o70ya2EVweHgJtwqBkr6DaoO0CETToFKsI";
    $accesstoken = "329620819-0tbQsQ7yx9BV5E6SzPaP39UAlDBuUokwRqgw075H";
    $accesstokensecret = "iL0divFR8xjTWQj9de511YxBpKkduE8dcOCRRlMrM";

    function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
      $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
      return $connection;
    }

    $interval = 600;

    $cache_file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache/' . $username . '_' . $limit;

        if (file_exists($cache_file)) {
                $last = filemtime($cache_file);
        } else { $last = false; }

        $now = time();

        if ( !$last || (( $now - $last ) > $interval) ) {

                $context = stream_context_create(array(
                        'http' => array(
                                'timeout' => 3
                        )
                ));

        $connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
        $twitter_feed = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$username."&count=".$limit);

                $cache_rss = serialize($twitter_feed);

                if (!empty($cache_rss)) {
                        $cache_static = fopen($cache_file, 'wb');
                        fwrite($cache_static, $cache_rss);
                        fclose($cache_static);
                }

                $rss = @unserialize(file_get_contents($cache_file));
        } else {
        $rss = @unserialize(file_get_contents($cache_file));
        }

    echo json_encode($rss);

endif;

?>
```

Comment: what do you meant under "that it's not being executed"?

Comment: Hi!, its a twitter feed and its suposed to retrieve tweets from specific twitter acount but its not working, the tweets are not showed.. I have this widget working on another server but its not mine, i cant see the conf.

Comment: You should provide error messages you run into, if any. Like, when you opening page with that script, what errors are shown in error console? Is it complaining about unexistent script at location `include/twitter/tweets.php?username=coinnova_ok` ? What is placed at location `include/twitter/` on your's nginx server in document root?

Comment: Hi, I'm not getting any error from console. you can check it from this url: http://ec2-52-24-39-27.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/actividades.html  at your right you will see the feed.  This is the working version of the page on another server http://www.co-innova.net/actividades.html .
Also I`m not getting any error on /var/log/nginx/error.log .

Comment: Yours script at address `include/twitter/tweets.php?username=coinnova_ok` returns `false`. It's, probably, because it requires some configuration, and you forget to configure it. Show that script source code, if possible.

Comment: I dont think the error belongs to the php code, as i said, this same code works perfectly on another server. Also i will upload the code for you :D, but check my php.info please, maybe you found something wrong there.

http://ec2-52-24-39-27.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/include/twitter/info.php

Note: I put the info.php under /include/twitter/ to ensure i can execute php code under this directory.

Comment: thanx, see my answer

Comment: Eh, and remove `info.php`, it's not very useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen from `tweets.php`, there only one point, that can return `false` as response:

```
echo json_encode($rss);
```

Which means, `$rss` variable is always empty, is a `false` or can't be json-encoded. That variable is set in two lines of script, each looking the same:

```
$rss = @unserialize(file_get_contents($cache_file));
```

That means, that file at path `$cache_file` is empty/unaccesible. Which leads us to point, where that file is written to:

```
$cache_rss = serialize($twitter_feed);

if (!empty($cache_rss)) {
    $cache_static = fopen($cache_file, 'wb');
    fwrite($cache_static, $cache_rss);
    fclose($cache_static);
}
```

if you add following code just before `$cache_rss = serialize($twitter_feed)` line:

```
print_r($twitter_feed);
```

After visiting `include/twitter/tweets.php?username=coinnova_ok` you should be able to see large dump of tweets. If only mere print for one variable with value of `false` is printed, then there are problems with authentication/fetching tweet from twitter api.

Othervise, if there indeed appears large print, then there are problems with saving fetched tweets into cache file. And path to that file is looking like:

```
$cache_file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache/' . $username . '_' . $limit;
```

So, in folder with script `tweets.php` there must be folder `cache`, accessible for writing.

Navigate to yours `include/twitter/` folder on the server, create there `cache` folder (if needed), and give it writing access rights for `php` scripts (usually `0750` or `0770`: full rights to owner, ful/read/execute to owner goup).

*Note: don't remember to remove `print_r($twitter_feed);` line after all issues got fixed.*